# Does this 'if [ -e ${MY_VARIABLE} ]' check if a variable exists in linux?

Tags: linux

I am looking at a bash script and it has a statement like this in it:

```
if [ -e ${MY_VARIABLE} ]
```

What does the -e parameter do? Does it check if the variable exists?

Comment: `man test` tells you what each option to `test` or `[` does. It's not reasonable to have a separate Stack Overflow question for each and every such flag, much less each and every possible thing someone might _speculate_ that a flag does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ -e ${MY_VARIABLE} ]
```

does not check if the variable exists.  (For that, use `${MY_VARIABLE?}` or `${MY_VARIABLE+}` (or `:?` and `:+`) depending on what you want to do.)

The `[` command never sees the string `MY_VARIABLE`.  The shell parses the string `${MY_VARIABLE}` and passes its expansion to `[`.  If MY_VARIABLE is not set (or is the empty string), the shell invokes the command `[ -e ]` and tests whether or not the string `-e` is empty (it is not).  If MY_VARIABLE is set and non-empty, then `[` is executed with some arguments.  if MY_VARIABLE did not contain any whitespace (more accurately, if it doesn't contain values in IFS), then `[` sees exactly 3 arguments (`-e`, the expanded value of `${MY_VARIABLE}`, and `]`) and checks if the path named by the second argument exists in the file system.  If MY_VARIABLE does contain elements of IFS, then `[` gets more than 3 arguments and (probably) emits an error message complaining about unexpected arguments.  (It is not necessarily an error if $MY_VARIABLE is subject to field splitting.  For example, if ${MY_VARIABLE} expands to the string `/ -a -e /etc`, then `[` will be invoked with the arguments `-e` ,`/`, `-a`, `-e`, `/etc`, and `]` and will check if `/` and `/etc` exist in the filesystem.)

Much of the behavior described above is rightly considered obscure, and is one of the primary reasons that best practice encourages the use of double quotes; `if [ -e "${MY_VARIABLE}" ]` is one of the preferred ways to check if the file named in $MY_VARIABLE exists.

Comment: `[ -e ]` is not an error -- it's an equivalent to `[ -n "-e" ]`, checking whether the string `-e` is nonempty (which it always is guaranteed to be) and thus always true.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, yes. Thanks.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be a shell script, then it is invalid. Either `if test -e "${MY_VARIABLE}"` or `if [ -e "${MY_VARIABLE}" ]`. `-e` itself is an invalid command, but the [`test`/`[`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) binary has such an option.

`-e` checks if a file exists. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> `-e` FILE
> FILE exists

NB. Always quote your variables, otherwise your script will not run (properly) or might perform unintended actions if a variable's value expands to several words (put differently: your variable contains whitespace)

Comment: I forgot the brackets but there is no doulble quote sit is like this: if [ -e ${MY_VARIABLE} ]

Comment: @DataCoder, leaving out the double quotes makes it deeply buggy -- you don't know how many arguments to `[` will be expanded to. You could have something like `MY_VARIABLE='thing-that-does-not-exist -o 1 = 1'`, and expanding with quotes will thus be true because `1 = 1` is true, even though `-e thing-that-does-not-exist` is false.

Answer (score -1):

No this command checks if a file of any type exists. Your variable is probably a string with a file path?

Print out the value of the variable to see if it is a path.

Comment: That's what it _should_ do, but because of the missing quotes its actual behavior is more interesting/surprising. For example: In the empty-string case, it just tests whether `-e` is a nonempty string, which it is, so it always returns true. In the case where it's a legit filename but with spaces in it, behavior depends on what's on each side of those spaces, but _most often_ the result will be a test syntax error. And then you have cases like `nonexistent-thing -o 1 = 1` where no such file exists but the result is true anyhow.